# ColdFusion: Add application event handlers dynamically

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Is there a way to dynamically register application event handlers such as listening to `onRequestEnd` programmatically without rolling my own event infrastructure on top of the static listeners?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve here. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @AdamCameron I have some reusable features that need to be able to hook themselves to application events such as `onRequestEnd`. I was wondering if there was a way to add event handlers dynamically or the only way to listen to these events is within `Application.cfc`? If so I'll have to roll my own event system on top of the current architecture...

Comment: Right, I'm with ya. Might be an idea to add that to the body of the question, rather than leave it as a comment though. Let me think: I think you're sunk as far as a native solution goes, but I'm sure any of the "usual suspect" frameworks out there will let you do this?

Comment: FW/1 (Framework One) and related technogies of DI/1 (Dependency Injection One) and AOP/1 (Aspect Oriented Programming One) do a lot of this. They basically work by tapping into the request lifecycle and expanding on it. http://framework-one.github.io/documentation/

Comment: I've never tried do this with Application.cfc, but I'll note that ColdBox MVC has an event model called interceptors. There are built-in events or you can register your own. They are programmatically configurable on the fly.   Events can even be chained and run async.  I'd say it's the best solution to this.  Disclaimer: I'm part of the ColdBox project.